# Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl() "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

```
let storage = firebase.storage();
let storageRef = storage.ref("EnglishVideos/" + movieTitle + "/" + movieTitle + "_full.mp4");
    console.log(storageRef); // looks OK, no error messages
```

The above code works, the object returned from Firebase Storage has the correct location, no error messages.

But `getDownloadUrl()` doesn't work:

```
let myURL = storageRef.getDownloadUrl();
console.log(myURL); // TypeError: storageRef.getDownloadUrl is not a function
```

The error is `TypeError: storageRef.getDownloadUrl is not a function`. It seems like a prototype chain bug. I'm using AngularJS, maybe I didn't inject a necessary dependency into my controller? I injected `$firebaseStorage` into the controller but it didn't help. My calls to Firebase Realtime Database from this controller are working fine.

Answer (score 13):

It's `getDownloadURL`, not `getDownloadUrl`. Capitalization. My working code is

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("EnglishVideos/" + movieTitle + "/" + movieTitle + "_full.mp4");
  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    console.log(url);
  });
```

The "[official](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html)" version is

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage.ref("folderName/file.jpg");
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url);
});
```

Note that I needed a `()` after `storage`, i.e., `storage()`.

Comment: This works for me as well, thank you. But how come, that if i init the storage in the constructor ( --> constructor(public storage: AngularFireStorage) {  } ) i can not chain .then() after this.storage.getDownloadURL() but after this.storage.upload(x, y).then() is not a problem?

Comment: I wrote the solution for your "then(...)" problem below

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas David Kehoe's solution got me nearly there.

I was still getting the error:

*ERROR TypeError: storageRef.getDownloadURL(...).then is not a function*

Here's my solution:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

and then inside my function:

```
var storageRef = this.storage.ref('myFolder/myFile.jpg');
storageRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise().then(function (url) {
    console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was trying to call `getDownloadURL();` on the upload task i.e

```
var upload=storage.child(`Testing/abc.png`).put(chosenFile);
//.....
//.....
upload.getDownloadURL();
```

solved it by doing

```
  var ImgUploadRef=storage.child(`Testing/abc.png`);
  var upload = ImgUploadRef.put(chosenFile);
   //....
   //....
   ImgUploadRef.getDownloadURL();
```