# Firebase storage getDownloadUrl is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, firebase-storage

I'm working on a vue app with firebase and I have referred to the [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676807/firebase-storage-getdownloadurl-is-not-a-function) questions and haven't found any solution to my problem.
What I want to do is store the download URL to my events database.
My code:

```
var stRef = st.ref(`event-photos/${eventId}`) // st is firebase.storage()
var upTask = stRef.put(this.fileBlob)
upTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
  this.uploadValue = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100
  }, error => {
  console.log(error.message)
  }, () => {
    upTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadUrl().then(url => {
      db.collection('events').doc(eventId).set({
        image_url: url
      }).then(() => {
        alert('Event creation successful')
      }).catch(error => {
        alert(error.message)
      })
   })
})
```

I have taken the code from [this](https://medium.com/@puoygae/tutorial-how-to-upload-files-using-firebase-fbe598538c52) page (see Example of registering an event handler).
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
var stRef = st.ref(`event-photos/${eventId}`)
var upTask = stRef.put(this.fileBlob)
```

to

```
var upTask = st.ref().child(`event-photos/${eventId}`).put(this.fileBlob)
```

and I am getting the downloadUrl with the function. So I guess we can't put the path in the ref, instead we have to use child.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on) listener, I would suggest that you use the [`then()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) method, which returns a Promise, in order to chain the different Promises returned by the asynchronous tasks (i.e. `getDownloadUrl()` and `set()`).

The following should therefore do the trick:

```
  var stRef = st.ref(`event-photos/${eventId}`); // st is firebase.storage()
  var upTask = stRef.put(this.fileBlob);

  upTask
    .then(snapshot => {
      return snapshot.ref.getDownloadUrl();
    })
    .then(url => {
      return db
        .collection('events')
        .doc(eventId)
        .set({
          image_url: url
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: still getting the same error in alert 'snapshot.ref.getDownloadUrl is not a function'

Comment: That seems really odd, what is the value of `firebase.SDK_VERSION`? By the spec, this code should run fine. If not, it's worth filing a bug report.